# Parsing Credit Card data from magnetic stripe reader using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Ok, So I have an html form that is displayed like so:

```
   <span style='required'>*</span> - Indicates required field.
   <div class='fields'>Swiped Information</div>
     <input type=text name='swiped' id='swiped'>
   </div>
   <div class='fields'>First Name</div>
    <input type=text name='first_name' id='first_name'><span style='required'>*</span>
   </div>
   <div class='fields'>Last Name</div>
    <input type=text name='last_name' id='last_name'><span style='required'>*</span>
   </div>
   <div class='fields'>Expiration</div>
    <input type=text size=8 name='expiration' id='expiration'><span style='required'>*</span>(MMYY)
   </div>
   <div class='fields'>CVV Code</div>
    <input type=text size=8 name='cvv' id='cvv'><span style='required'>*</span>
   </div>
   <div class='fields'>Credit Card Number</div>
    <input type=text name='card' id='card'><span style='required'>*</span>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <div class='buttons'></div>
    <a onclick="readCard();" style="cursor:pointer; color:red;">Swipe Credit Card</a>
   </div>
```

My knowledge of this kind of stuff is very poor. I have a basic little Credit Card Reader that plugs into my computer via USB. I am wanting to be able to swipe a credit card and have my website parse the information into the form fields that are above.

I have added an `onclick=readCard();` event to a link below my form and when that is pushed java script is initiated to put focus on the `Swiped Information` field which will store the string of data from the magnetic stripe reader.

```
function readCard () {

   document.getElementById('swiped').focus();

}
```

My thoughts would be that the employee would hit "Swipe Credit Card" which would make the Swiped Card Information field have focus and would fill that field with the string, then the javascript would break that information up into pieces and fill the form accordingly.

I have searched high and low to try and find a solution and the closest I could come was a tutorial that used asp.net as the language and I can't do that. Either PHP or JavaScript. Thanks in advance.

All I need to do is break that long string up into multiple and display the appropriate parts in the html form.

P.S. I'm not worried about form validation ATM, I will be taking care of that after I manage to make it fill the form fields! Thanks!

UPDATE:

I created a JSFiddle although the java script I put in doesn't appear to be working. 
http://jsfiddle.net/r8FJX/

UPDATE:

As per the comments below, I have added an example of the data sent from my card reader to the computer. I went in and replaced every number in the string with randomly typed fake numbers and replaced my name with a fake one. (Sorry scammers!)

```
%B6545461234613451^DOE/JOHN^00000000000000000000000?;6545461234613451=984651465116111?
```

I am assuming this how the code above is laid out, I can't find any documentation:

```
%Bcardnumber^lastname/firstname^expDate?;cardnumber=expDate?
```

Comment: could you give an example of the swiped credit card data?

Comment: You will need to let us know the details of the credit card as well - we can probably figure out from looking the card number and name - but we have little chance of guessing wich the CVV and date fields  are.

Comment: What do you mean "details" I'm not posting my real credit card information

Comment: Right - thats fine of course. But youve just given us a load of random numbers there - how are we to know which of those numbers represents a date, and which represent a CVV, and which represent a credit card number? Without going through the code of the credit card reader (if its available) there is no way of us knowing - so, which of the numbers above is the valid from date? Which is the expiry date? Thats what I'm saying - does the manufacturer not provide any example data?

Comment: You're still missing CVV number, but I will continue my answer without it.

Comment: That may be something that will be required to be typed in manually, I'm not sure. If I find documentation I may be able to expand on your answer in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1)

```
var card_data = "%B6545461234613451^DOE/JOHN^00000000000000000000000?;6545461234613451=984651465116111?"

var details1 = card_data.split("^");

var card_number = details1[0];
card_number = card_number.substring(2);

var names = details1[1].split("/");
var first_name = names[1];
var last_name = names[0];

var details2 = details1[2].split(";");
details2 = details2[1].split("=");

var exp_date = details2[1];
exp_date = exp_date.substring(0, exp_date.length - 1);
exp_date = exp_date.substring(2, 3) + "/" + exp_date.substring(0,1);
```

Option 2)

```
var pattern=new RegExp("^\%B(\d+)\^(\w+)\/(\w+)\^\d+\?;\d+=(\d\d)(\d\d)\d+$");
var match = pattern.exec(card_data);

card_number = match[1];
first_name = match[3];
last_name = match[2];
exp_date = match[5] + "/" + match[4];
```

Then Do:

```
document.getElementById("first_name").value = first_name;
document.getElementById("last_name").value = last_name;
document.getElementById("card").value = card_number;
document.getElementById("expiry").value = exp_date;
```

Comment: With option 1 I recieve this error in google chrome console: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'length' of object  is not a function on line 73

Comment: Also: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined on line 65

Comment: my bad, length is a property, not a method (remove the () )

Comment: Ok, So I am missing the Expiration date?

Comment: check my latest update - sorry it took so many tries - it must be late :)

Comment: We are back to: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined on line 73 after copying and pasting option 1 again.

Comment: I did just run the code in jfiddle without any issues. Try running it line by line, and see what details2 is right before.

Comment: Ok a page refresh fixed it never mind (my bad) but the expiration date shows up as: `16071200000010300000` when it needs to show up as MM/YY

Comment: can I assume that the real expiration date of the card is 07/16?

Comment: The real expiration date is 11/14

Comment: :S In that case I've no idea - how does that number result in 11/14?

Comment: My reader must have read wrong, I ran it 4 times with the same result of: 141110100000595 which could result in 11/14 right?

Comment: yeah - that makes sense - for the same reason I thought the above was going to be 07/16. Check the latest update.

Comment: That gives me 1/1 But can you move this to a chat? I don't have enough reputation to and this becoming a little long.

Comment: You dont have enough rep to chat - play with the indexes, you want the 3rd and 4th digit followed by the 1st and 2nd digit.

Answer (score 0):

I had success with the follow for expiration date:

exp_date = exp_date.substring(2, 4) + "/" + exp_date.substring(1, 3);

Answer (score 0):

Just For Future viewers like myself that was searching. The expiry needed to be adjusted. This will make the expiry look like... 10/18.  Not 10/81 like I was getting...

Below shows the corrected formatted date of ex: 10/18 not 10/81 or 1/1

```
exp_date = exp_date.substring(2, 4) + "/" + exp_date.substring(0,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

(For future people trying to parse USB credit card reader data)

There are two (sometimes 3) tracks of data, they are separated with `?`. The expiry date is duplicated on the first track and the second track. If you want to read enough data to charge a credit card you can ignore the Track 2 data (everything from the `;` onwards).

The CVC is not stored on the magnetic stripe data. You'll have to disable the CVC check in your payment processor. With Stripe you can do it at https://dashboard.stripe.com/radar/rules.

```
let parse = readerData => {
    let card = readerData.match(/%B([0-9]+)\^([A-Z /.]+)\/([A-Z /.]*)\^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/);

    let lastName = card[2].trim();
    // 'LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME.MR' is possible
    let firstName = card[3].trim().split('.')[0];
    let fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;

    return {
        exp_month: card[5],
        exp_year: card[4],
        number: card[1],
        name: fullName,
    };
}

parse('%B6545461234613451^DOE/JOHN^21040000000000000000000?;this part does not matter')
// {exp_month: "04", exp_year: "21", number: "6545461234613451", name: "JOHN DOE"}
```

If you're using [Stripe.js v2](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js/v2) you can pass the object returned by `parse()` directly to `Stripe.card.createToken()`.

I've seen `LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME MIDDLENAME` in sample data, this code should turn that into `FIRST MIDDLE LAST`.

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card#Financial_cards for more info.

I don't know if doing this is [legal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard). Newer USB credit card readers encrypt the data they read (you have to send the data to their api (and pay them) to decrypt it).

If you're having issues with the regex try https://regex101.com/ for debugging it.